# Display a nice div when http error code 500 was caught

Tags: html, angular, error-handling

I have created a simple `ErrorHandler` class which looks:

```
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    handleError(error : any){
        //console.log('test error ', error.status);
        if(error.orginalError.status === 500){
            alert('An unexpected error occured 500');
            console.log('from AppErrorHandler ', error);
        }
        else {
            alert('An unexpected error occured');
            console.log('from AppErrorHandler ', error);
        }   
    }
}
```

As you may see I only display an `alert` at the page when an error occures. After some time of digging I have not found a solution to display that error in any kind of `div` with bootstrap class `alert alert-danger`. Is it possible in general?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the following:

- Create a service which contains your errors
- In your errorhandler, add the error to the errorService
- Create a component which will be your "nice div"
- Place this component in your `AppComponent` so it will always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a 3rd party library, there is an awesome package **"angular2-notifications"** to display notifications.

Here is a link to get it:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications

... and you can find the documentation here:

> https://jaspero.co/resources/projects/ng-notifications

... and ofcourse the source code with examples here:

> https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications